# I am having rounding off problem while working with certain data in Excel sheet

Tags: excel, rounding-error

I have thousands of data in an sheet which are actually head wise monthly revenue generated by my organisation.
The data are all  numeric and in unit figure. I have to generate report in thousand fig rounded off to zero decimal place.
When the rounded off figs are summed up manually, the total comes up a little more than the total calculated by auto sum of Excel.
My boss is not ready to listen to any technicality issue such as 'Excel keeps numeric data in floating format in the background.....'etc and wants the both total to be equal.
Is there any method to deal with this problem ?

I tried Round formula but the problem is not solved. An example of the figure is shown below :-

Head    Amt.(in unit)   Amt. in
thousands
A210    1291520         1292
B652    2265432         2265
C510    4837615         4838
D412    8394567         8395
E333    6211258         6211
F670    2811020         2811
Total   25811412
Total R/O  25811    25812 manually in thousand                  calculated

Comment: Add a footnote. Seriously. Something along the lines "Totals may not tie due to rounding error" or something to that effect.

Comment: Assuming your values are stored in range B1:B6, write this in a cell `=SUM(ROUND(B1:B6/1000;0))` and **instead of just pressing enter to confirm** press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to make it an array formula.

Comment: Bury the rounding error in the largest item, D412. If you make its rounded value 8394 the rounded values then sum to the rounded sum of the unrounded values. If the rounded difference is 2 rather than 1 bury it in the 2 largest items, etc.